# Sed command for handling string replacements by matching the pattern

Tags: date, awk, sed

I am create a command using sed, which should work for these three  scenarios.

```
echo "a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 06/09/2023 06:30:30 06/09/2023 06:32:45 SU 307404729/1 0" |sed -E "s#([^/]*)?([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})#echo \1\$(date -d '\\2' +'%d-%^h-%Y')#g;s/echo //2ge"
```

is producing the desired result as below.

```
a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 09-JUN-2023 06:30:30 09-JUN-2023 06:32:45 SU 307404729/1 0
```

essentially its reprinting the given input record while converting the date to `DD-MMM-YYYY` format as shown in the result above.

but there is slight variation of the input record where second date is blank (-----). so to process that record format, i had to modify the command slightly as shown below.

```
echo "a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 06/09/2023 06:30:30 ----- RU 307404729/1 0" |sed -E "s#([^/]*)?([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})#echo \1\$(date -d '\\2' +'%d-%^h-%Y')#g;e"
```

and produced the desired result as below one.

```
a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 09-JUN-2023 06:30:30 ----- RU 307404729/1 0
```

and there is a third scenario where the record format having the both dates go blank like shown below.

```
a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh ----- ----- OH 307404729/1 0
```

and it should just reprint this 3rf format record as it is.

i have been trying to write this command in single line which works for al these 3 scenarios  of the record formats given above and struggling.

could some one throw some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change where the command is executed i.e the first pass before removing the duplicate `echo` and change the condition for the removal of additional `echo`

```
$ echo "a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 06/09/2023 06:30:30 06/09/2023 06:32:45 SU 307404729/1 0
a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 06/09/2023 06:30:30 ----- RU 307404729/1 0
a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh ----- ----- OH 307404729/1 0" | \
sed -E "s#([^/]*)?([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})#echo \1\$(date -d '\\2' +'%d-%^h-%Y') #ge;s/echo //g"
a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 09-JUN-2023 06:30:30 09-JUN-2023 06:32:45 SU 307404729/1 0
a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 09-JUN-2023 06:30:30 ----- RU 307404729/1 0
a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh ----- ----- OH 307404729/1 0
```

Comment: can we make it work for 3rd scenario where both the dates go blank like this?  a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh ----- ----- OH 307404729/1 0"

Comment: there should be a space between date and time a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 09-JUN-202306:30:30 09-JUN-2023 06:32:45 SU 307404729/1 0  but in your output both the date and time printed with out  any space

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any version.

```bash
awk '
BEGIN{
  split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec",months,",")
}
{
  line=$0
  while(match(line,/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/)){
    val=substr(line,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    split(val,arr,"/")
    val2=arr[2]"-"months[sprintf("%01d",arr[1])]"-"arr[3]
    sub(val,val2)
    line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/ ..\/..\/.... / $(date -d & +"%d-%^h-%Y") /g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

Replace each date with a command substitution and finally evaluated the echoed line.

Alternative using only sed:

```
sed -E 's/$/\n01JAN02FEB03MAR04APR05MAY06JUN07JUL08AUG09SEP10OCT11NOV12DEC/
        :a;s/ (..)\/(..)\/(....) (.*\n.*\1(...))/ \2-\5-\3 \4/;ta;P;d' file
```